# Timer issue on Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have encountered a serious issue in asp.net which is stopping me going further.

The issue is due to server side timer control. The following is the scenario,

When main page loads , timer will start automatically and it should keep run throughout the application. My page contains Infragistics controls.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" onload="UpdatePanel1_Load">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="true" Interval="10000" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <ig:WebDataMenu ID="WebDataMenu1" runat="server" OnItemClick="wdmenu_Context_ItemClick">
            <Items>
                <ig:DataMenuItem Key="0" Text="Add" >
                </ig:DataMenuItem>
                <ig:DataMenuItem Key="1" Text="Edit">
                </ig:DataMenuItem>
            </Items>
       <ClientEvents ItemClick="wdmenu_Context_ItemClick" />
        </ig:WebDataMenu>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

If i open model dialog and after 2 to 3 sec , i am  closing the model dialog... the wdmenu_Context_ItemClick server side event (which is for opening model dialog ) is firing **two times...**

Also on click of that button , i am opening model dialog using java script which is shown below

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function wdmenu_Context_ItemClick(sender, eventArgs)
    {

        var win = window.showModalDialog("Default2.aspx", "Dialog", 'center:yes;resizable:no;dialogHeight:500px;dialogwidth:660px');
    }
    </script>

</head>
```

Please help me regarding this....

Comment: I don't wholly understand your question, but I think you have a few issues.  A server side timer control will not run for the length of your application - ASP.net code in general will only run for the lifetime of a page request - what are you trying to do?

Comment: you should consider using ajax timer control: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/

Comment: I don't think it's worth downvoting. Noobs need to learn IMHO... Anyway you (username too complex to retype, me too lazy for c&p) have a serious understanding problem of ASP.NET and should possibly expand your questions with your real needs (do you need the panel to be closed after X seconds for example?)

Comment: Interesting, before [Yngve B. Nilsen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/325836/yngve-b-nilsen) edited the question it had -2 and now it got three upvotes.